# Why is the md5 returning same hashes for two different file names

Tags: php, md5

I have two video file having different file names.But when I md5 filenames both are returning same hashes. Below are the file names.

1.*\test\downloadvideo\ans-70055040.hd.mp4*

2.*\test\downloadvideo\ans-70055298.hd.mp4*

```
$this->_video_md5 = md5_file("\test\downloadvideo\ans-70055040.hd.mp4");
$this->_videoo_md51 = md5_file("\test\downloadvideo\ans-70055298.hd.mp4");

echo "md5".$this->_video_md5
```

will return *md551f767588587184d13b8c9e6ed550166sh190d2078270d4ea1cb570b1de7*
*fb890bc761bda9a*

```
echo "md5".$this->_videoo_md51
```

will return *md551f767588587184d13b8c9e6ed550166sh190d2078270d4ea1cb570b1de7
fb890bc761bda9a*

How can I get two different md5 hashes for the file names.

Comment: `md5|sha1_file` functions return hash of file contents not filename. If both files are identical you'll end up with two equal hashes.

Comment: By the way, the filenames should be inside quotes...

Comment: @AndreschSerj : I am guessing his problem is with the quotes. (And later will be with the escaping of the backslashes)

Comment: quotes is not the problem.I forget to add the codes here.Even with codes it is returning same

Comment: Please just COPY/PASTE from your code and results. Please don't retype and let out stuff.

Comment: So from the bottom: You have two identical files. You compare the files using md5_file and get the exact same hash. This is correct. This is supposed to be like this because you compare two identical file contents, not filenames. If you want to compare filenames, just compare the filenames using `md5('yourfilename')` and not `md5_file`as stated here and as stated in the documentation of both those functions.
What is unclear to you still?

Comment: Did you check if the backslashes were escaped? ... `\t` in `\test` otherwise becomes a tab, for example. So make it `\\test`. (Check my answer below)

Comment: @user993516 Is one of those videos distorted by any chance? Maybe you are dealing with a deliberate hash collision? Is this a torrented video that doesn't want to play?

Answer (score 2):

As written above, `md5|sha1_file` return the hash of the file contents, not including the file's name.

A possible "solution" would be to hash the outcome of both the filename and the hash of the file itself, which will be a unique hash again.

Comment: I have palyed that video files they are different,but returning same hash

Answer (score 1):

Use `md5("\test\downloadvideo\ans-70055298.hd.mp4");` instead of md5_file, if you want to hash the filename, not the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

To get different hashes, change the contents of the files, so the files are not identical.

If you want to check the filenames only , use `md5("filename")` and not `md5_file("filename")`

Also you don't seem to have quotes around the filename. They should be there!
And escape backslashes!

So

```
md5_file(\test\downloadvideo\ans-70055298.hd.mp4);
```

should be

```
md5_file("\\test\\downloadvideo\\ans-70055298.hd.mp4");
```

otherwise, `\t` ist interpreted as a *tab character*. 
Due to that, your `md5_file` get's an invalid filename both times, thus returning the same hash.

Comment: I have checked the file contents,they are different

Comment: Your problem is maybe the filename is not inside quotes!

Comment: @user993516 that would be inconsistent with your question.